# Why is this else statement being considered first than one of the if values above?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This function loops through an array of strings. If the string doesn't start with an `#` it's wrapped with a `p` tag. If the previous string of the string is a `#` or a `* * *` it's wrapped with a `p` tag with the class `ni`

```
function replaceParagraphs(data) {
  data = data.split('\n\n')
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if (data[i].match(/^[^#]/g)) {
      var content = data[i].replace(/\n(?=\w)/g, ' ').replace(/\n(?=$)/g, '')
      if (data[i - 1].match(/^#/g) || data[i - 1] === "* * *") {
        data[i] = '<p class="ni">' + content + '</p>'
      } else {
        data[i] = '<p>' + content + '</p>'
      }
    }
  }
  data = data.join('\n\n')

  return data
}
```

But it seems like `data[i - 1] === "* * *"` is not being considered, since I end up with an output like this:

```
## Test

<p class="ni">Lorem “ipsum?” dolor ‘sit!’ amet</p>

<p>Consetetur eirmod</p>

<p>* * *</p>

<p>“Ipsum?” “‘dolor’” sit! amet, consetetur eirmod tempor—invidunt ut labore</p>
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT:**

Oh, based on the answers and comments I realized that it's because the code produces `<p>* * *</p>`

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: `data[i] = '<p>' + content + '</p>'` You wrap every string in a `p` Surely it will not start with `#` or equals `* * *`

Comment: Good observation agent Mulder :P

Comment: Shame it's an answer in the comment section. Comments are for requesting clarification and berating people; nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you replaced `* * *` with `<p>* * *</p>` in the previous step.

That conditional `data[i - 1].match(/^#/g) || data[i - 1] === "* * *"` can only ever possibly be true on the first iteration.

Consider writing into a fresh array, for clarity and to resolve issues like this.